# i'm trying to create SubPages on my next.js project but it keeps showing up as a page when clicked

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

i'm trying to create SubPages on my next.js project but it keeps showing up as a page when clicked
i have my src/pages which carries my pages. (index.js, Menu.js, location.js etc ).in the same directory (src/pages) i have another folder named menu which carries the subpages i'll like to render in my Menu.js page. here's my Menu.js wit me redering the subapages

```
function Menu() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { subpage } = router.query; // Get the subpage from the URL

  const subpageComponents = {
    appetizers: <Appetizers />,
    'local-dishes': <LocalDishes />,
    shakes: <Shakes />,
    beverages: <Beverages />,
  };

  const currentSubpage = subpage || 'appetizers';

  return (
    <div className='bg-cyan-50 mb-14'>
      <div className='flex justify-center text-2xl lg:text-5xl text-cyan-800 my-10'>
        <h1>MENU</h1>
      </div>
      <nav className='mb-20'>
        <ul className='flex justify-around text-neutral-800 text-lg underline md:text-2xl lg:w-[70%] mx-auto'>
          <li>
            <Link href="/menu/appetizers">Appetizers</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/menu/localdishes">Local Dishes</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/menu/shakes">Shakes</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/menu/beverages">Beverages</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div>
        {/* Display the subpage component */}
        {subpageComponents[currentSubpage]}
      </div>
      {/* Footer or other elements */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

now on entering the menu.js page, the subpages display below as subpage rendering appetizer.js as default subpage. but when i click on the link to the subpages, the menu page disappears leaving me with the clicked subpage as a main page